# Calling function from Jupyter Notebook not reading string

Tags: python, qt, function, jupyter-notebook

This seems simple.  I have a Jupyter Notebook with the following code allowing for a file dialog so the user can select a file to analyze.  There are a couple of different files used and it is important the user selects the proper file in the proper order.  I am trying to add information to the Window title so the user knows which file the script is looking for.

Here is the Notebook code:

```
import PCB_utility
f_name = PCB_utility.get_file('Select Bitwise data file')
df_bitwise = pd.read_excel(f_name, sheetname = 'lvtemporary_653630', header=(0))
f_name = PCB_utility.get_file('Select ARINC 429 data file')
df_ARINC = pd.read_csv(f_name, sep = '\t', header=(0))
```

The file dialog works.  The user selects the file, and the program just does what it needs to.  I am trying to make it a little more user friendly.
PCB_utility looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
#from PyQt4.QtCore import *

def get_file(Instructions):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, Instructions, '/')
    return(filename)
```

The problem is the Instructions are NOT making through to the dialog box.  I manually entered this function into the IPython section and it works beautifully.  It doesn't add the extra text when I call it from the notebook.  It just has the standard 'Open File'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that finally worked:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


def get_file(Instructions):

# Create an PyQT4 application object.
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 

# The QWidget widget is the base class of all user interface objects in PyQt4.
    wid = QWidget()

# Get filename using QFileDialog
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(wid, Instructions, '/')
    return(filename)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I needed to add the PyQt4 application and widget, then close it.  I have to admit I don't quite understand why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

OP already found solution, but for others that looking for the same thing - you can use IPython magic command for enabling IPython GUI event loop integration, to make working external GUI called from IPython (i.e. Jupyter notebook):

```
# Magic (we must tell IPython that we will be running an external Qt GUI)
%gui qt5

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

def select_file(directory='./'):
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,
                                        'Select file...', 
                                        directory,
                                        filter='All files (*)')
    return fname[0]
```

As original question is for PyQt4, above command `%gui qt5` should be replaced with `%gui qt4` or only `%gui qt`.

To do the same thing without magic commands (similar to OP's solution):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog

def select_file(directory='./'):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,
                                        'Select file...', 
                                        directory,
                                        filter='All files (*)')
    return fname[0]
```